# Having "permission denied" when I try to upload image to /media/ dir, DJANGO

Tags: python, django, apache

I setup django framework into apache server, normally there is no problem when I try to insert record to DB. But if I try to upload something into `media` dir, permission problem occurs. I already give the `chmod -R 755 to /var/www/` project's parent folder. But still having the problem.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

and `.conf` settings are below.

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/

        Alias /static /var/www/example.com/src/static
        <Directory "/var/www/example.com/src/static">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /var/www/example.com/media
        <Directory "/var/www/example.com/media">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/apis_error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/apis_access.log combined

        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/example.com:/var/www/venv36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup example.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/src/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/example.com/src>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea what is the problem here?

Comment: 755 denotes **RWX** (user) **R**w**X** (group) **R**w**X** (other). If you aren't the user, you could not write to that directory. Try `766` or `777`. Another, check the directory owner. It might be **root**. And unless you are **root** you cant write. You can change directory owner by `sudo chown -R user:group folder`

Comment: well said. 766 is not solved it,  but giving 777 to `/media` folder is solved the problem. BUT,  is it okay to give 777 is to media folder? @Pax

Comment: just change the folder owner to `www-user` or `current-user` is the better option than setting 777 to folder.

Answer (score 0):

can you check the owner of the /media. Change the owner to www-data if it is another user who owns it

Comment: You could include the chown command here for reference.